# Converting expression with >>= to do notation

Tags: haskell, monads, code-translation, do-notation

I have the following code

```
newtype State s a = State { runState :: s -> (s,a) }    
evalState :: State s a -> s -> a
evalState sa s = snd $ runState sa s

instance Functor (State s) where
  fmap f sa = State $ \s ->
    let (s',a) = runState sa s in
      (s',f a)

instance Applicative (State s) where
  pure a = State $ \s -> (s,a)

  sf <*> sa = State $ \s ->
    let (s',f) = runState sf s
        (s'',a) = runState sa s' in
      (s'', f a)

instance Monad (State s) where
  sa >>= k = State $ \s ->
    let (s',a) = runState sa s in
      runState (k a) s'

get :: State s s
get = State $ \s -> (s,s)

set :: s -> State s ()
set s = State $ \_ -> (s,())

bar (acc,n) = if n <= 0
              then return ()
              else
              set (n*acc,n-1)

f x = factLoop

factLoop =  get >>= bar >>= f
```

And

```
 runState factLoop (1,7)
```

gives  `((5040,0),())`

I'm trying to write the function

```
 factLoop =  get >>= bar >>= f
```

using the do notation

I tried

```
 factLoop' =  do
                (x,y) <- get 
                h <-  bar (x,y) 
                return ( f h)
```

But that does not give the correct type which should be `State (Int, Int) ()`

Any idea ?

Thanks!

Comment: Get in the habit of writing explicit type signatures for your functions. It will help you see that `f h` has the type `State (Integer, Integer) b` that `factLoop` has, and therefore you don't need `return`.

Comment: [BTW](https://pastebin.com/qtT0XDAn). shorter, clearer, pseudocode -- not a valid Haskell code. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`>>=` is `infixl 1` (left-associating binary operator), so what you really have is

```
f x = factLoop

factLoop =  get >>= bar >>= f
         =  (get >>= bar) >>= f
         =  (get >>= bar) >>= (\x -> f x)
         = do { x <- (get >>= bar)
              ; f x }
         = do { _ <- (get >>= bar)
              ; factLoop }
         = do { _ <- (get >>= (\x -> bar x))
              ; factLoop }
         = do { _ <- do { x <- get 
                        ; bar x }
              ; factLoop }
         = do { x <- get 
              ; _ <- bar x 
              ; factLoop }
```

the last one is because of the monad associativity law ([*"Kleisli composition forms a category"*](https://wiki.haskell.org/Monad_laws)).

Doing this in the principled way you don't need to guess. After a little while you get a feeling for it of course, but until you do, being formal helps.

Answer (score 7):

Just remove the `return` on the final line :

```
factLoop' =  do
                (x,y) <- get 
                h <-  bar (x,y) 
                f h
```

There is no `return` in your original code, so there should be none in the `do` notation version either. `do` notation simply "translates" uses of `>>=`, as you've already done.